# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException "Name must not be null!" when updating MongoDB collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

I am facing below issue when I am going to update a existing collection entry in mongoDB. I am using Spring boot 2.0.

my existing MongoDB collection entry is like below. I'm going to update the "external_item" of below collection. It has a null key in that json posion.

```
{
    "TestItem" : {
        "item1" : "value1"
    },
    "external_item" : {
        "" : "keyIsEmptyOfThisValue",
        "key2" : false
    },
    "links" : [],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T05:24:44.014Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T05:24:44.014Z")
}
```

For that I m using below payload with the PUT method with a REST API

```
{
"external_item" : {
        "" : "keyIsEmptyOfThisValue",
        "key2" : true
    }
}
```

when updating gives below issue. It says Name must not be null!. How can I get updated the MongoDB content in this way ??

````
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$Field.<init>(QueryMapper.java:591)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createPropertyField(QueryMapper.java:216)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.UpdateMapper.createPropertyField(UpdateMapper.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertSimpleOrDBObject(QueryMapper.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.UpdateMapper.getMappedObjectForField(UpdateMapper.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:410)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doUpdate(MongoTemplate.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateFirst(MongoTemplate.java:985)
    at com.pearson.socket.core.dao.MongoDriverImpl.updateFirst(MongoDriverImpl.java:127)
    at com.pearson.socket.core.dao.AbstractDAOImpl.updateFirst(AbstractDAOImpl.java:92)```
````

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug somewhere in old versions of `spring-data-mongodb` that caused this.

Consider updating to newer `spring-boot` and `spring-data-mongodb` versions, e.g I know that in `spring-boot 2.2` that uses `spring-data-mongodb 2.2.6` updating an entity with empty map key works.